# Templates doesnot name a type error in c++ for function templates

Tags: c++, templates

I want to sort array of any data type for that I use sort function inside  swap() function is used. I've tested this with integer array and 
I'm getting a error like  : **‘T’ does not name a type
 T sort(T t[],int n)**
[image: errors]  and some other errors(Check the image) . I'm a beginner in c++ so explain me what's wrong with this code and how to resolve it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
void swap(T,T);
T sort(T t[],int n)
{ 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=i+1;i<n;i++)
        if(t[i]>t[j])
          swap(t[i],t[j]);


    return t;
}
void swap(T &x ,T &y)
{
     T temp;
     temp=*x;
     *x=*y;
     *y=temp;
 }
int main() {
int n;
cout<<"enter n value";
cin>>n;
int arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>arr[i];
int result[n];
result=sort(arr,n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 cout<<result[i];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: the indentation

Comment: You need to repeat the `template<...>` part for every template function.

Comment: Also note that C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why to use template part everywhere

Comment: Lastly, about arrays again, you can't assign to an array, only copy to it.

Comment: Actually, it seems you're only guessing about syntax and behavior, which is a bad way to learn any language. [Get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and start learning properly.

Comment: `using namespace std;` followed by things that have names which can be found inside `std::` is asking for trouble.

Comment: "why to use template part everywhere" because that is the syntax of the language

Comment: Images are not helpful. Please use text.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude after repeating template<....> in every statement it works finely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the some edits now its working.Thank you guys.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  
template <class TT> void swape(TT &x ,TT &y)  
{ 
    x=x+y;
    y=x-y;
    x=x-y;
}

template <class TT> void  sort(TT t[],int n)
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
           if(t[i]>t[j])
               swape(t[i],t[j]);


 }
  int main() {
      int n;
       cout<<"enter n value";
      cin>>n;
      int arr[n];
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      cin>>arr[i];
      sort(arr,n);
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      cout<<arr[i];
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use addition and subtraction to swap if you are writing a template function. The sole purpose of templates is to write generic code, independent of type, and in your case that swap will only work for integers which defeats the purposeof it being a template.